# Is there an eslint plugin that can check the dependency after a 'npm prune --production'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

My build steps: npm install, npm run build, npm prune --production, then produce artifact

Is there a lint plugin that can check that I am not importing dev dependencies by mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md

You can set option `devDependencies` to false. ESLint will show errors if you import from devDependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such plugin.

ESLint doesn't check if the modules that you require are installed. It only checks if you use a module that you required it first, or rather if you declared a variable that stores the module. It doesn't actually check if the `require()` call would work because it would have to run it and it doesn't do that.